# How to access ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer with credentials (token)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, authentication

I know I simply need to append a token=XXX to the export query string but how, in code, do we initialize "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer" to use credentials?  In my case I only want to provide a token value.

Here's my code to show how I've hacked around this...probably good enough for my needs but seems wrong.  Should I be creating a Credentials instance and associating it with the layer?

```
function createDynamicLayer(options, map) {
    var dataset = options.dataset;
    var query = ioQuery.queryToObject(acme.right(dataset.CacheURL, "?"));
    var imageParameters: esri.layers.ImageParameters = new esriImageParameters();
    var credentials: esri.Credential;

    imageParameters.format = query.format || "png";

    var url = acme.left(dataset.CacheURL, "/export");
    var layerName = acme.left(acme.right(dataset.CacheURL, "/export/", true), "?");
    if (layerName) {
        layerName = layerName.split(",");
        layerName = array.map(layerName, "return parseInt(item, 10)");
        lang.mixin(imageParameters, {
            layerIds: layerName,
            layerOption: esriImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_SHOW
        });
    }

    if (query.token) {
        credentials = new IdentityManagerBase.Credential({ token: query.token });
        url += "?" + ioQuery.objectToQuery({ token: query.token });
    }

    var layerOptions = lang.mixin({}, lang.getObject("layers.esri.dynamic", esriConfig), {
        id: options.id,
        imageParameters: imageParameters
    });

    //Takes a URL to a non cached map service.
    var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(url, layerOptions);
    return dynamicMapServiceLayer;
}
```

Comment: I'm *not* looking for this as a solution but rather an example of how credentials and layers are supposed to work together:

url += "?" + ioQuery.objectToQuery({ token: query.token });

Comment: Are you asking how to secure that layer so that it requires tokens? Or how to access the layer in JavaScript after it has been secured?

Comment: Services already requires tokens; this is a jsapi question: What it the intended technique for using credentials to access imagery?

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/credential.html, https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer.html

These docs make credentials appear to be a read-only attribute on the layer but how was that achieved?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this one? I'm trying to access secure dynamic layers with a token using the js api and can't figure it out.

Comment: @VBAHole: No, I am appending ?token=XXX to the endpoint and the token is send in from a server which communicates with the JSAPI services.

Comment: I am doing it the same way: adding `?token=XXX`.  Seems to work just fine.